# AWK : Merge two files based on key and latest date

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have 3 files in Folder:/home/amaxxxx/EXTRACT/2w/

```
File 1.txt
A|B|02/26/2014 15:00:37
--edit A|B|9999|02/26/2014 15:00:37

File 2.txt
A|B|04/04/2014 12:00:37
--edit A|B|1|04/04/2014 12:00:37

File 3.txt
A|B|02/01/2014 12:00:37
--edit A|B|9999999|02/01/2014 12:00:37
```

I was successful in merging all files using

```
awk -F"|" '!a[$1FS$2]++' /home/amaxxxx/EXTRACT/2w/* > mergedfile.txt

**Output:**
A,B,02/26/2014 15:00:37
```

But I want merge two files with latest date to get output as below removing timestamp. Kindly guide

```
A|B|04/04/2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (requires `GNU awk`):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
{
    fld4 = $NF;
    sub(/ .*/,"",$NF);
    split(fld4, d, /[:/ ]/);
    ts = mktime(d[3]" "d[1]" "d[2]" "d[4]" "d[5]" "d[6])
    if(a[$1,$2]) {   
        line[$1,$2] = (ts > a[$1,$2]) ? $0 : line[$1,$2]         
    }
    else {
        line[$1,$2] = $0   
        a[$1,$2] = ts   
    }
}
END {
    for(x in line) print line[x]
}' f1.txt f2.txt ...
```

#### Explanation:

- You use `GNU awk` `mktime` function to calculate the time specified in the third column
- You update the key in hash only when the time is more recent. If time found on the same key is older, you keep the newer value.

Comment: Hi JS, I want to remove timestamp also

Comment: If files where in this format A|B|9999|02/26/2014 15:00:37 & A|B|9|04/04/2014 12:00:37 and I want to merge files based  on $4. I can print x FS a[x]. How can I bring $3 of record with date 04/04/2014

Comment: Hi JS , Can you please explain if(a[$1 FS $2]) {line[$1 FS $2] = (ts > a[$1 FS $2]) ? $0 : line[$1 FS $2] in you code..

Comment: @Awknewbie Sure, it is a ternary operation. Similar to `if-else` loop. I am checking the time against what is stored in the array. If time in array is bigger, keep it as is if it is smaller replace the array element with the bigger time. I cleaned up the code a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk -F '|' '{if ( a[$1 FS $2] < $0 ) {a[$1 FS $2]=$0} } }
             END {for (k in a) { print gensub(" .*","",a[k]) } }' /home/amaxxxx/EXTRACT/2w/* > mergedfile.txt
```

Will do it, but please note, the output will be unsorted. If you need sorted output, it can be done, and I'm leaving that part to you.

Now this works this way:

1. If the value of `a[$1 FS $2]` is less then the actual line then update it's value to the actual line. (This willbe checked for every line in every file.)
2. Finally print every line (which now has the largest value of $3).

You can [see it in action here at ideone](http://ideone.com/ySEhM4). (Note, this sets the `FS` variable in the `BEGIN` block as ideone does not allows to use the `-F` switch for `awk`.

Comment: Hi Zolt / JS I will be very thankful if you can explain the code.Plus I want to remove timestamp also

Comment: @JS웃 thanks for pointing this out, I had updated the answer. (Also updated the comparison).

Comment: How will awk determine a full line is greater than actual line for a[$1 FS $2]. Also why a[$1 FS $2] > $0 null data. Sorry if I am asking silly questions here

Comment: Based on it's ascii value. And I don't get what you mean by null data.

Comment: 1.I tried the code with  ( a[$1 FS $2] > $0 ). I thought it will give least value record but I got blank file as output                    2.Also if I want to specifically check if $3 of incoming line is greater (rather than $0) what should I do . I tried  gawk -F '|' '{if ( a[$1 FS $2] < $3 ) {a[$1 FS $2]=$0} } } END {for (k in a) {print a[k]} }' but prints data with least date

Comment: I had updated the solution, with example at http://ideone.com/ySEhM4 and printing only the last date. It works for me.

Comment: Thank You Zsolt.. But if you are checking with ASCII value, in case like (please see my edited File 1&2.txt in question) the File1 output will be printed. For that I tried with with below code but still gawk -F '|' '{if ( a[$1 FS $2] < $3 ) {a[$1 FS $2]=$0} } END {for (k in a) { print a[k] } }' /home/amaxxxx/EXTRACT/2w/* > mergedfile.txt